# File path error in pipeline for spark notebook in azure synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I have a spark notebook which I am running with the help of pipeline. The notebook is running fine manually but in the pipeline it is giving error for file location. In the code I am loading the file in a data frame. The file location in the code is abfss://storage_name/folder_name/* and in pipeline it is taking abfss://storage_name/filename.parquet\n

This is the error
{
"errorCode": "6002",
"message": "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: abfss://storage_name/filename.parquet\n  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4(DataSource.scala:806)\n\n  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4$adapted(DataSource.scala:803)\n\n  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)\n\n  at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)\n\n  at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)\n\n  at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)\n\n  at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)\n\n  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)\n\n  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)\n\n  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)\n\n  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)\n\n  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)\n\n  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)\n\n  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)\n\n  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)\n",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "notebook_name",
"details": []
}

Comment: Can you please include more information about the code you are using and images of the pipeline.

Comment: In the code we are reading a file stored in adls gen2 var_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("file_path.parquet")  In the pipeline I have selected the notebook in which this code exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error mainly happens because of permission issue, the synapse workspace required lack of permissions to access storage account, so you need to grant `storage blob contributor` role.

To add `storage account contributor` role to your workspace, refer this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-grant-workspace-managed-identity-permissions)

[image: Ref1]

And also, make sure to check whether you are following `ADLS gen2` proper syntax or not.

```
abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>
```

**Sample code**

```
df = spark.read.load('abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/samplefile.parquet>', format='parquet')
```

**For more detail information refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA35MbcM7XA).**

Comment: The workspace is already having storage account contributor access and file path is also correct as you mentioned. Also, the notebook is running fine manually.

Comment: hi @avg, please edit and provide details information about code and error running pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Added my synapse workspace under the required access. Hence, worked.